# Photon-Gluon annihilation in QCD

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics, matrix-elements

I am starting to learn about QCD, and I wanted to calculate the squared matrix elements for photon-gluon annihilation into a quark and an anti-quark. However, I am having trouble writing down the correct matrix elements at tree level and computing the spin and color sum of the averaged matrix element.

I found this [FeynCalc webpage](https://feyncalc.github.io/FeynCalcExamplesMD/QCD/Tree/GaGl-QQbar), but I did not find it extremely helpful. I would really appreciate any help or resources.

The specific process I am interested in is
$$\gamma(p_1)+g(p_{2})\rightarrow q(p_{3})+\bar{q}(p_{4}).$$
So the relevant Feynman rules and diagrams are:

[image]

I believe that I have made a mistake with the arrows on the first (left) diagram; I think they should be in the opposite direction. Thus the matrix elements for the first (left) diagram and the second (right) diagram are:
$$M_{1} = -ie^2Q\left(v(p_{4})T^b \gamma ^{\alpha}\left(\frac{\not{p_{1}}-\not{p_{4}}+m}{(p_{4}-p_{1})^2-m^2}\right)\gamma^{\beta}\bar{u}(p_{3})\epsilon_{\alpha}(p_{1})\epsilon_{\beta}(p_{2})\right)$$
and
$$M_{2} = -ie^2Q\left(\bar{u}(p_{3}) \gamma ^{\mu}\left(\frac{\not{p_{3}}-\not{p_{1}}+m}{(p_{3}-p_{1})^2-m^2}\right)T^a\gamma^{\nu}v(p_{4})\epsilon_{\mu}(p_{1})\epsilon_{\nu}(p_{2})\right)$$
However, I am still not sure that I have applied the rules correctly.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried thus far, and where you are having a conceptual problem. thanks.

Comment: @joseph h is it fine to post the Feynman diagrams written by hand?

Comment: Sure. But if you are having problems with the math, post that here too using latex. Cheers.

Comment: @joseph h  I have added more details to my question. Hope this clears things up. Thanks

Comment: very good. thanks.

Comment: $q$ and $\bar q$ are not identical particles, so the $u$-channel diagram isn't needed...question mark?

Comment: @JEB I see, Then are there any other diagrams that contribute to this process at tree level? Thanks

Comment: Wait, maybe...I think you can cross the gluon and photon? idk I prefer to write diagrams with p1, p2, p3, p4 at same spot and move the lines around....it's just clearer for me. (and it may be equivalent to the diagram I told you to (maybe) take out.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors.

The fermion line on the left diagram should be reversed, since the fermion is outgoing.
Then one should trace the fermion line **backwards**, so you have
$$
\bar{u}(p_3) ... v(p_4)
$$
on both diagrams.
I assume you know that the spinors are vectors in the Dirac space in which the gamma matrices live, so this expression is a scalar in this space, $\bar{u}$ is a row vector and $v$ is a column vector.

Then one usually draws another reverse arrow over the outgoing fermion line to imply that it is actually outgoing.

I drew it for you. This are all the diagrams that contribute on tree level.

[image]

Then you should of course note that photon and gluon couplings are not equal! So you better use different symbol for them, conventionally $e$ for em coupling and $g$ for the strong coupling.